# How to get the Android Activity color from decorview?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

I am working an a Android automation project using Robotium tool. Now I want to get the color of Activity, I am setting the Activity color through decorView. Please let know is any possible way to get the color.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you have a parent layout,

use this method to get the layout background, and save this in drawable. and use this in your reqired place.

```
Drawable background = layout.getBackground();
```

Comment: Thank you for immediate reply. Actually, I am not setting the color for layout , I am setting color for whole activity using getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(some color);
Could you help me if you know this solution.
Thanks

Comment: try this: Drawable background=getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground();